# CORS in IIS issue with credentials and wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: node.js, iis, cors, credentials

I inherited a fairly basic site that serves up data and handles some socket connections. It's running NodeJS behind IIS using iisnode as a bridge. That's all working fine from a "serve normal pages" perspective.

Part of the problem is that the actual connections to the server are coming from desktop clients where the content is loaded through a different application as a gadget and from potentially changing and varying parts of the network, mobiles devices, etc. etc. i.e. - an unknown number of client domains.

I already set Access-Control-Allow origin to * to just throw the barn doors open but now am getting the following error in the client:

> 11:29:57.668 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy
>   disallows reading the remote resource at
>   ‘http://server/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1486150196479-0’.
>   (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header
>   ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’). 1 (unknown)

I have attempted to set the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials explicitly to false (as well as true, as well as leaving it out entirely) but none of my attempts have allowed me to get past this.

The raw response headers look like this currently:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Content-Type,Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 969
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 03 Feb 2017 19:30:21 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

I can't seem to sort out after looking at A LOT of CORS sites and articles over the last few days why it's still complaining about Credentials - and more specifically, how do I get around this?

Thanks!

***UPDATE 2017-02-06***

The client code is not terribly exciting. Since the server is NodeJS behind IIS, all I'm really doing for this is implementing a socket connection:

```
var socket = io('http://' + currentServer, {path: '/broadcast/socket.io', reconnection: false, forceNew: true});
socket.on('update message', function (data) {
// do some fancy things
}
```

This works from within the same domain.

I've also been doing some more digging based on sideshowbarker's comments that led me to this [article](http://www.carlosag.net/articles/enable-cors-access-control-allow-origin.cshtml) There are some extra steps to add the variables, and some other things to get that piece working.

My applicationHost.config currently contains this section:

```
<location path="Default Web Site">
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <allowedServerVariables>
                <add name="CAPTURED_ORIGIN" />
                <add name="RESPONSE_Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
            </allowedServerVariables>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

and my web.config is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite> 
        <rules>
            <rule name="Fail bad requests">
                <match url="." />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="localhost" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="AbortRequest" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Capture Origin Header"> 
                <match url=".*" /> 
                <conditions> 
                    <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern=".+" /> 
                </conditions> 
                <serverVariables> 
                    <set name="CAPTURED_ORIGIN" value="{C:0}" /> 
                </serverVariables> 
                <action type="None" /> 
            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules> 
            <rule name="Set-Access-Control-Allow-Origin for known origins"> 
                <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access-Control-Allow-Origin" pattern=".+" negate="true" /> 
                <!--<action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" /> -->
            </rule> 
        </outboundRules> 
    </rewrite>
    <tracing>
        <traceFailedRequests>
            <add path="*">
                <traceAreas>
                    <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket" verbosity="Verbose" />
                </traceAreas>
                <failureDefinitions statusCodes="400-599" />
            </add>
        </traceFailedRequests>
    </tracing>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

on the outboundRules I currently have the action type="Rewrite" line commented out because when I enable that, it throws up an error.

```
HTTP Error 500.52 - URL Rewrite Module Error.

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Most likely causes:
•IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
•IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
•IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
•The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
•The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Detailed Error Information:
Module: RewriteModule 
Notification: SendResponse 
Handler: StaticFile 
Error Code: 0x80070585 

Requested URL: http://localhost:80/iisstart.htm 
Physical Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\iisstart.htm 
Logon Method: Anonymous 
Logon User: Anonymous 
Request Tracing Directory: C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles
```

The Failed Request Logs are not overly helpful, they show the following for the warning:

```
411.  -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 
ModuleName: RewriteModule 
Notification: SEND_RESPONSE 
HttpStatus: 500 
HttpReason: URL Rewrite Module Error. 
HttpSubStatus: 52 
ErrorCode: Invalid index. (0x80070585) 
ConfigExceptionInfo:
```

Comment: It would be useful if the question also included the client JavaScript code

Comment: Please try `<action type="Rewrite" value="{CAPTURED_ORIGIN}" />` or maybe even `<action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" />` (and if `value="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" ` works there, then the entire `<rule name="Capture Origin Header">` element can be dropped).

Comment: Ah, that first one got it, thanks! I didn't realize with all the smashing of my head against the keyboard that those substitutions were locally scoped. Much appreciated!

Comment: Super—glad it’s finally working for you. (And I updated my answer to use `<action type="Rewrite" value="{CAPTURED_ORIGIN}" />`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the loop on this. The answers and suggestions posted above worked fine for an IIS-only website in regards to this issue.

My problem was some bug in the IIS-Node library that ultimately forced me down the path of migrating the entire stack to NodeJS and running all of the modules natively direct in Node.

Comment: This is not an actual answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

The question doesn’t show the client code which is sending the request that causes that error, but:

The client code must be using XHR or the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) (or using jQuery or other library that calls one of those), and that code is either setting the XHR [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) property to `true` or is calling the Fetch [Request constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) with an options object having the `credentials` option set to `include`.

When that’s the case and the server response has an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header, your browser will log the error cited in the question.

So one solution is to change the JavaScript client code so it’s not setting XHR `withCredentials` to `true` and not calling the Fetch Request constructor with `credentials: 'include'`.

Another solution is to make your server-side code take the `Origin` request-header value and echo it to the`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response-header value.

For IIS, you can do that with the [URL Rewrite Module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) by adding the following to your IIS config file (`Web.config` or `ApplicationHost.config` file in `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\`).

```xml
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <rewrite> 
            <rules> 
                <rule name="Capture Origin Header"> 
                    <match url=".*" /> 
                    <conditions> 
                        <add input="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" pattern=".+" /> 
                    </conditions> 
                    <serverVariables> 
                        <set name="CAPTURED_ORIGIN" value="{C:0}" /> 
                    </serverVariables> 
                    <action type="None" /> 
                </rule> 
            </rules> 
            <outboundRules> 
                <rule name="Set-Access-Control-Allow-Origin for known origins"> 
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
                           pattern=".+" negate="true" /> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{CAPTURED_ORIGIN}" /> 
                </rule> 
            </outboundRules> 
        </rewrite> 
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Then remove whatever other existing code/config is setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

**Note:** The above is a modified version of the example config file in the step-by-step guide [Enable CORS for specific domains in IIS using URL Rewrite](https://www.carlosag.net/articles/enable-cors-access-control-allow-origin.cshtml).

Comment: Thanks, Your post looks like it refrences this article, at least in part, except where you are not using a Rewrite Map: [link]http://www.carlosag.net/articles/enable-cors-access-control-allow-origin.cshtml[link] I will update the configuration pieces that I've implemented, as well as the client side code - it's socket.io connections, that I'm trying to connect.

Comment: Yeah the part I left out isn’t necessary unless you also want to restrict access to requests from only particular domains. (And I updated my answer to credit the source for the config file.)

Comment: Yes, I first tried just implementing your proposed entry, which looks like exactly what I need to do for "All Domains" - but I'm still hitting a 500.52 error on this line:  `<action type="Rewrite" value="{C:0}" />`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I had both http and https bindings on one website with Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
in this case http request will fail with the above error.
you can create a separate website for http binding and remove Access-Control-Allow-Origin header from it.