# After upgrade to asp.net 5.2.3, CORS isn't working for "*" origins

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, cors

I have a project using web api and one using asp.net mvc.
They are configured using CORS module.

The project using Web Api is configured to allow **any** origin because it's deployed on Azure and it's an OData endpoint, so we don't know who is going to consume it.

### OData endpoint configuration

```
// inside configuration
config.EnableCors();

// controllers
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public void ...
```

From my MVC client, using Angular `$http` we issue an authenticated request using **Bearer token** which looks like this one:

### Request sent

```
Request URL:http://myodata.com/Products
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:123.123.123.123
```

And this is the header sent

```
Host: myodata.com
Authorization: bearer 123-ABC
Origin: http://myclient.com
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Referer: http://myclient.com/
```

The problem lays in the response as you can see here:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Because **after we upgraded from 5.2.2 to 5.2.3** the CORS module is sending out `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

And clearly, from the browser, we get this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myodata.com/Products. 
The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header 
in the response must not be the wildcard '*' 
when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. 
Origin 'http://myclient.com' is therefore not allowed access. 
The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest 
is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

But the call succeed actually, it bombs on the Angular side.
We didn't have this issue until today, after we upgraded from 5.2.2 to 5.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to try is setting the header using the [URL Rewrite Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323350/access-control-allow-origin-with-multiple-domains/31084417#31084417), by adding the following to your `Web.config` or `ApplicationHost.config` file in `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot\`.

```xml
<configuration> 
    <system.webServer> 
        <rewrite> 
            <outboundRules> 
                <rule name="Make Access-Control-Allow-Origin echo Origin"> 
                    <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
                           pattern=".+" negate="true" /> 
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="{HTTP_ORIGIN}" /> 
                </rule> 
            </outboundRules> 
        </rewrite> 
    </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

If the above doesn’t work, then you can try the version in the answer over at [CORS in IIS issue with credentials and wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031885/cors-in-iis-issue-with-credentials-and-wildcard-in-access-control-allow-origin/42035527#42035527).

Another approach: [in the `global.asax` or other code for your service, add something like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323350/access-control-allow-origin-with-multiple-domains/17329532#17329532):

```
if (ValidateRequest()) {
    Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Request.Headers["origin"]);
    Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Methods");
    Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
}
```

...the most important part of that being this:

```
Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Request.Headers["origin"]);
```

In either case the end effect should be: your backend takes the value of the `Origin` request header and echoes it back as the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response-header value.

Comment: Actually this is what I was looking for
Because the Origin, it doesn't matter which one, has to be considered valid anyway
Thanks

Comment: Also, here is the explanation of why
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors

Section: 'Passing credentials in cross origin requests'